# How to add header and footer on every page bottom not end of the content using Thymeleaf PDF?

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

Can anyone please suggest how to add header top and footer bottom (not end of the content) on every page using Thymeleaf PDF generation.

The page will generate dynamically.

Comment: Hi LAD Thanks, i used html header tag and footer tag but its not working it means footer coming all pages end and header showing only starting page.

Comment: Any one can answer my question i am eager to waiting someone answer